# These malicious codes are in all the pages of my chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYTbY.png)

I don't know where they came from

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this blog post about how to get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask